# Is it possible to resize images to specific size?

Tags: iphone

I have an application which has around 800 images. Is there any way to re size the images to specific size. I have tried using the following code:

```
UIImage *image = [[UIImage imageNamed:recipeObj.recipeImage]
    _imageScaledToSize:CGSizeMake(64.0f, 61.0f)
 interpolationQuality:1];
cell.imageView.image = image;
```

This code snippet gives me a warning. Is there any other alternative way for resizing images?

Comment: I'm guessing the warning is UIImage might not responsd to selector _imageScaledToSize:interpolationQuality: - try not using private API calls?

Comment: 'UIImage' may not respond to  '-_imageScaledToSize:interpolationQuality:'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could look at this blog post :

http://vocaro.com/trevor/blog/2009/10/12/resize-a-uiimage-the-right-way/

At the end he's attached the resizing code as a category on UIImage.